# What is a real story of god Kaal Bhairav?

Tags: vedas, temple, brahma, story

What is a real story of god Kaal Bhairav and also what is a story associated with his temples,Shree Kaal Bhairav Mandir, Ujjain and Kaal Bhairav Mandir,Varanasi.

Answer (score 1):

The Summary of the story is that after the competition between Lord Brahma and Lord Vishnu while finding the head and feet of Bhagwan Shiva Lord Brahma cheated and lied which angle Bhagwan Shiva and he created Bhagwan kalabhairava to cut the fifth lying head of Lord Brahma. And in the same time Bhagwan Shiva created the sin Brahma hatya who followed Bhagwan Kala Bhairava till Kashi where he got rid of this sin.

The story of Bhagawan Kala Bhairava can be found in [this](https://www.wisdomlib.org/hinduism/book/shiva-purana-english/d/doc226404.html) and [this](https://www.wisdomlib.org/hinduism/book/shiva-purana-english/d/doc226405.html) chapter of Sri Shiva Purana.

As for the Ujjain Bhagawan Kala Bhairava temple, it's mentioned in [this](https://www.wisdomlib.org/hinduism/book/the-skanda-purana/d/doc425636.html) chapter of Sri Skanda Purana. Here Bhagawan subdued the Matrika Matas.

I hope this clarifies all your queries. Prd..